# C# library, constructor with type of another project

Tags: c#, libraries

I'm currently developing a small app to learn some new concepts. I developed some classes that parse the MBR and different partitions from the disk.

So I had the idea of making it more modular. 
I thought of bringing all this methods to a Library called DiskParsers, that parses data. 
And another library who calls native methods to perform disk I/O. 
Now the problem is that the constructor has a parameter of a custom type, written by me in the disk IO lib, who handles reads and writes to physical drive. 
My library doesn't know what that type is.

How can I solve this? Using generics? Bundling an interface of disk I/O class to my parser lib? My parser lib should accept byte buffers only, and have no relation of custom types?

Comment: Add a reference to the IO library from your DiskParsers library?  Or use interfaces to decouple the libraries?

Comment: Add another library containing only DTOs or interfaces. Hard to answer without concrete code.

Comment: @DStanley so then I should copy the dll to the parent directory of my exe?

Comment: I agree with the decoupling using an intermediate interface library.

Comment: No, it should be in the _same_ directory as the executable, unless you use a custom search path.  Visual Studio should take care of that for you if you add a reference.

Comment: @CodeCaster i'm thinking the following logic... 

Main program calls a method on disk io library to retrieve some bytes of data, and then the main programan calls a parser method on parser lib and use a parameter the bytes obtained, so is more generic in terms of usage, the parser decouples from the custom type and use data from a byte array, shouldn't that be the best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your parser library in such a way that it is agnostic of where the data to parse comes from. For instance something like this:

```
public class MBRParser
{
    public MasterBootRecord Read(Stream stream)
    {
        // parsing logic
    }

    public MasterBootRecord Read(IMBRReader reader)
    {
        // parsing logic
    }

}

public interface IMBRReader
{
    MasterBootRecord Read();
}
```

Now, a client program can take your I/O library to provide the parser with a `Stream`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stream = new IOLibrary.Stream();
        var mbrParser = new MBRParser();
        var mbr = mbrParser.Read(stream);
    }
}
```

Or your client program implements a concrete `IMBRReader`:

```
public class NativeMBRReader : IMBRReader
{
    public MasterBootRecord Read()
    {
        // native I/O methods to read MBR
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var mbrReader = new NativeMBRReader();
        var mbr = mbrReader.Read();
    }
}
```

Either way: your libraries do not need to know each other. Only the client program needs a reference to both of them. Referencing the libraries can be done in multiple ways. The easiest: put both library projects and the client program in one solution. In the client project add project references to the libraries.